# Android Spannable not working in recycler view adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, spannablestringbuilder

I have a recycler view and want to change color of some part of textview text.

Here's my code:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyEarningsAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    public ArrayList<WageItemDataSet> wageItemList;
    private Context context;
    private Spannable spanText;
    private ForegroundColorSpan fcs;
    private RelativeSizeSpan rss;
    public MyAdapter(Context context) {
        wageItemList = new ArrayList<>();
        this.context = context;
        fcs = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK);
        rss = new RelativeSizeSpan(0.8f);
    }
 @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_wage_list, parent, false));
    }
    @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            WageItemDataSet item = wageItemList.get(position);
            spanText = new SpannableString("Fare: "+item.totalFare);
            spanText.setSpan(fcs, 0, 4, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            spanText.setSpan(rss, 0, 4, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            holder.tvFareAmount.setText(spanText);

        }

        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            TextView tvFareAmount;
            public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                tvFareAmount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvFareAmount);

                tvFareAmount.setTypeface(openSansRegular);

            }
        }
}
```

It doesn't change color or the text size. What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi I have implemented the same thing and its working for me. You have to make one class that extend ClickableSpan like it as below:

```
    public class TextSpan extends ClickableSpan {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View widget) {
      TextView tv = (TextView) widget;
      Spanned s = (Spanned) tv.getText();
      //int start = s.getSpanStart(this);
      //int end = s.getSpanEnd(this);
    }
  }
```

and then in your on onBindViewHolder() method you have to write this code as below

```
     SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
     builder.append("yourstring");
     builder.setSpan(new TextSpan(), builder.length() -        
     comment.length(),builder.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
     holder.tvFareAmount.setText(content);
  holder.tvFareAmount.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

I hope this will resolve your problem

Comment: @WOLF.L does it helpful

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me -

```
StringBuilder captionBuilder = new StringBuilder();
captionBuilder.append(yourString);
SpannableStringBuilder commentBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(captionBuilder);
commentBuilder.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.your_color)), start, end, 0);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried with Spannable, SpannableString, SpannableStringBuilder. Nothing works

Comment: Alright, I made it worked with `StringBuilder`. And it is working in my app. Just try it.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. This should be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    WageItemDataSet item = wageItemList.get(position);
    String value="Fare: "+item.totalFare;
    Spannable spanText = new SpannableString(value);        
    spanText.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 5, 13, 
    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    textview.setText(spanText);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below to achieve your goal...

```
public static void spanText(Context context, AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView editText, String replaceString) {
    String event = editText.getHint().toString();
    int startPos = event.indexOf(replaceString);
    int endPos = startPos + replaceString.length();

    Spannable spanText = Spannable.Factory.getInstance().newSpannable(editText.getHint());
    spanText.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.dark_yellow)), startPos, endPos, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    editText.setHint(spanText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try .append() instead of .settext()

```
holder.tvFareAmount.append(spanText)
```